Why are font sizes different across notepad++ panes? How do I make them the same?
I already have "Enable global font" and "Enable global font size" checked in the Style Configurator. But the font sizes are clearly different.


Almost looks like you zoomed (ctrl+scrollwheel) in one of the tabs.

Yeah, but I didn't, and I can replicate the pattern.
